# Sending an email causes - Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Basically what am i trying to do is to send an email:

```
-(void) sendAnEmail {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Hey, check this out!" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[@"testing@gmail.com"]];

        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"device cannot send email");
    }
}
```

There is no error, no warning. The output if this void is:

> BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

**How can I solve this?**

test device - 5S(8.3)

Comment: Is this code actually getting called?

Comment: Do you have any manipulations with CIFilter somewhere around?

Comment: well i was trying to send an email with attachment,the same problem occured so i try with something simple, this is the actual code

Comment: @alexburtnik wtf thank you so much for the hint - you are awesome :D can you explain why this is happening in an answer, i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From [this Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) I can understand that XPC services are supposed to prevent apps from crashing by separating unstable components somehow.
2. The crash itself is caused by some kind of a bug in CIFilter. 
   It's hard to tell what actually is wrong with your code, since the issue is obviously not with `MFMailComposeViewController`. If you are creating `CIContext` with options like this:

```
[CIContext contextWithOptions: @{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @(NO)}];
```

Try to replace `NO` with `YES`